# Call Javascript function via onchhange to change a src-attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I installed a webserver on my old PC that was just standing around and made movies accessible in the local network. I already wrote a php-script to display all movies in that folder (so i don't have to write down every single one and update it all the time), but that's not really user-friendly.

I would like to have a dropdown-menu with an iframe below and everytime you change the option in the dropdown-menu, the iframe shows the new movie.

My code until now:

```html
<div>
<form>
<select id="movielist" onchange="mvsrcchange();">
<option value="../Filme/Film 1.mp4">Film 1</option>
<option value="../Filme/Film 2.m4v">Film 2</option>
<!-- usw -->
</select>
</form>
<iframe id="mvframe" src="" width="960" height="400" frameborder="0">
</div>

<script>
var mvform = document.getElementById("movielist");
  
mvsrcchange() {
 var mvsrc = mvform.options[mvform.selectedIndex].value;
 var address = mvsrc;
 document.getElementById('mvframe').src = address;
}
</script>
```

But sadly it doesn't work and I can't find my mistake. When I change the selected movie, nothing seems to happen.

Thanks for every helpful answer,
Twisterado

Comment: {
  "message": "ReferenceError: mvsrcchange is not defined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 1,
  "colno": 1
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close iframe tag properly to make html valid and use function declaration syntax like this.

```
function mvsrcchange()
```

or

```
var mvsrcchange = function()
```

```html
<div>
<form>
<select id="movielist" onchange="mvsrcchange();">
<option value="../Filme/Film 1.mp4">Film 1</option>
<option value="../Filme/Film 2.m4v">Film 2</option>
<!-- usw -->
</select>
</form>
<iframe id="mvframe" src="" width="960" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
var mvform = document.getElementById("movielist");
  
function mvsrcchange(){
 var mvsrc = mvform.options[mvform.selectedIndex].value;
 var address = mvsrc;
 document.getElementById('mvframe').src = address;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Omg, how could i not see, that the iframe tag wasn't closed :D Thanks you so much, it works!

Comment: @Twisterado NP :) Glad to help